# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in Stack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: img_caption_shortcode()

Tags: php, fatal-error, captions

Why am I getting this error in my apache logs?

```
==> tech.michaelaltfield.net/error.log <==
[Wed Aug 23 00:00:09.968658 2023] [php:error] [pid 459909] [client 0.0.0.0:0] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/media.php:2147\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: img_caption_shortcode()\n#1 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(356): call_user_func()\n#2 [internal function]: do_shortcode_tag()\n#3 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/shortcodes.php(228): preg_replace_callback()\n#4 [internal function]: do_shortcode()\n#5 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(307): call_user_func_array()\n#6 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(191): WP_Hook->apply_filters()\n#7 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/themes/redacted/functions.php(309): apply_filters()\n#8 [internal function]: bfa_wp_trim_excerpt()\n#9 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(309): call_user_func_array()\n#10 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(191): WP_Hook->apply_filters()\n#11 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/post-template.php(429): apply_filters()\n#12 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/feed.php(226): get_the_excerpt()\n#13 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/feed-rss2.php(103): the_excerpt_rss()\n#14 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/template.php(770): require_once('...')\n#15 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php(1662): load_template()\n#16 [internal function]: do_feed_rss2()\n#17 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(309): call_user_func_array()\n#18 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(331): WP_Hook->apply_filters()\n#19 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/plugin.php(476): WP_Hook->do_action()\n#20 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/functions.php(1624): do_action()\n#21 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/template-loader.php(48): do_feed()\n#22 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php(19): require_once('...')\n#23 /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/index.php(17): require('...')\n#24 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/wordpress/htdocs/wp-includes/media.php on line 2147, referer: https://tech.michaelaltfield.net/feed/
```

I recently upgraded my server to use PHP 8.2. After I did, I started getting these fatal PHP errors in wordpress.

I was able to isolate the issue to one post containing a simple `[caption]` shortcode. I further distilled the shortcode to the following snippet, which throws the fatal error if it's added to any post

```
[caption]<a href="http://example.com"><img src="https://example.com/example.jpg" /></a> test[/caption]
```

Through trial-and-error, I found that the fatal error does *not* appear if I add an `id` option to the shortcode. For example, this is fine:

```
[caption id="whyuno" ]<a href="http://example.com"><img src="https://example.com/example.jpg" /></a> test[/caption]
```

According to the official wordpress documentation on the [caption shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Caption_Shortcode), the `id` option is not required (ie the option is, uh, optional).

I'm running the latest stable version of PHP (8.2) and the latest stable version of Wordpress (6.3).

What is causing this issue and how do I fix it?

Comment: See also https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/59206#ticket

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're mis-using the caption shortcode here

```
[caption]<a href="http://example.com"><img src="https://example.com/example.jpg" /></a> test[/caption]
```

You can fix it by **adding a width** option, which is *required* per the [official documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Caption_Shortcode#Options)

```
[caption width="1600"]<a href="http://example.com"><img src="https://example.com/example.jpg" /></a> test[/caption]
```

In any case, this is also likely a bug in Wordpress (misusing a shortcode shouldn't result in a PHP Fatal Error). See the following bug report:

- https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/59206